# Web api return 404

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing some automated integration test in visual studio on my web api controller. I've got the following code in my test:

```
var url = serverAddress + "/api/PostalCodes?postalCode=" + postalCodeToFind;
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

I get the following error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not
>   indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

The selfhost server used:

```
private const string serverAddress = "http://localhost:8080";

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(serverAddress);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2024 * 2024;
            config.MaxBufferSize = 2024 * 2024;

            server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        }
```

The weird part is that if I have my web api controller in IIS, the same URL will work just fine and return a value. I also have the same url doing a post (without the postalCodeToFind query parameter) and it also works well...

Any clues ?

Comment: Does it work when you just paste the link in your browser? It's possible that the API is configured to only accept POST-requests

Comment: A `POST` and a `GET` are not the same thing, so it's entirely possible to get a `404` for one and not the other at the same Url (whether that's recommended or not is another question). But to focus on the question: what is the value of `serverAddress` in your test?

Comment: If I do the get in the browser on my test selfhost server, the request hangs...

Comment: @DanPuzey I updated my question. Note that the serverAddress works for the post.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is not being loaded by the test.

Do you have a custom Resolver or are you expecting the baked in resolver to pick it up?

If you're using a custom Resolver (i.e. inheriting from DefaultAssembliesResolver), make sure the library containing the controller is being loaded.

If you're expecting the baked in resolver to pick it up, the library containing your controller needs to be in the directory that the test is running from.

Comment: The controller is being loaded, because the same url but done with a POST request works.